# Can't build gem with Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Why I can't install this gems?
I cloned a reporsitory from a friend who has a Windows PC too, and on their computer the gems work without any problems.

I got this error in my console:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
Der Befehl "make" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

make "DESTDIR="
Der Befehl "make" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug
-4.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0
/byebug-4.0.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing byebug (4.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '4.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```